# Google chart: Column Label exact value not approximate

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bar-chart, multiple-columns, column-chart

I have two charts:
1) google.charts.Bar
2) google.visualization.PieChart

The code is: https://jsfiddle.net/almiroleal/5w3n1cku/2/

```js
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar','corechart'], language:'pt_BR'});
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Vendedores', 'Valor', 'n de vendas'],
   ['Vendedor 1', 24685.27, 298],
   ['Vendedor 2', 34415.24, 58],
   ['Vendedor 3', 76171.08, 615],
   ['Vendedor 4', 60106,  649],
   ['Vendedor 5', 38779.04, 445]
  ]);

  var bar_options = {
   chart: {
    title: 'Vendas em Valores',
    subtitle: 'por Vendedores'
   },
   series: {
    0: { axis: 'valor'}, // Bind series 0 to an axis named 'valor'.
    1: { axis: 'qtd' } // Bind series 1 to an axis named 'qtd'.
   },
   axes: {
    y: {
     valor: {label: 'total em R$'}, // Left y-axis.
     qtd: {side: 'qtd de vendas', label: 'Qtd de Vendas'}  // Right y-axis.
    },
   }   
  };
 
  
  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('grafico1'));
  chart.draw(data, bar_options);

  var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Vendedores', 'Valor'],
   ['Vendedor 1', 24685.27],
   ['Vendedor 2', 34415.24],
   ['Vendedor 3', 76171.08],
   ['Vendedor 4', 60106],
   ['Vendedor 5', 38779.04]
  ]);
  var pie_options = {
   title: 'Percentual de Vendas',
   subtitle: 'por Vendedores',
   is3D: true
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('grafico2'));
  chart.draw(data2, pie_options );


 }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <div id="grafico1" style="width: 700px; height: 300px;"></div>
 <div id="grafico2" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Both are loaded, but the google.charts.**Bar** displays the label/tooltip of the first column the approximate value; does not display the exact value (bar charts display tooltips When the user hovers over the column) Example: The value for the "Vendedor 3" (Saller 3) should be 76171.08, but displays 76 Mil(I use the language:'pt_BR').

> google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar','corechart'],
>   **language:'pt_BR'**});

**How do I display the exact value with decimals in google.charts.Bar chart?**

Something strange. I tried to create a third graphic google.visualization.**ColumnChart** on the same page and graph 1 appeared with the label with exact value (not the approximate value). If you remove the graph 3, the values return to display approximate.

The code with ColumnChart
https://jsfiddle.net/almiroleal/cumtdhnh/1/

```js
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar','corechart'], language:'pt_BR'});
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Vendedores', 'Valor', 'n de vendas'],
   ['Vendedor 1', 24685.27, 298],
   ['Vendedor 2', 34415.24, 58],
   ['Vendedor 3', 76171.08, 615],
   ['Vendedor 4', 60106,  649],
   ['Vendedor 5', 38779.04, 445]
  ]);

  var bar_options = {
   chart: {
    title: 'Vendas em Valores',
    subtitle: 'por Vendedores'
   },
   series: {
    0: { axis: 'valor'}, // Bind series 0 to an axis named 'valor'.
    1: { axis: 'qtd' } // Bind series 1 to an axis named 'qtd'.
   },
   axes: {
    y: {
     valor: {label: 'total em R$'}, // Left y-axis.
     qtd: {side: 'qtd de vendas', label: 'Qtd de Vendas'}  // Right y-axis.
    },
   }   
  };
 
  
  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('grafico1'));
  chart.draw(data, bar_options);

  var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Vendedores', 'Valor'],
   ['Vendedor 1', 24685.27],
   ['Vendedor 2', 34415.24],
   ['Vendedor 3', 76171.08],
   ['Vendedor 4', 60106],
   ['Vendedor 5', 38779.04]
  ]);
  var pie_options = {
   title: 'Percentual de Vendas',
   subtitle: 'por Vendedores',
   is3D: true
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('grafico2'));
  chart.draw(data2, pie_options );

  var col_options = {
   chart: {
    title: 'Vendas em Valores - column chart',
    subtitle: 'por Vendedores'
   },
   series: {
    0: { axis: 'valor'}, // Bind series 0 to an axis named 'valor'.
    1: { axis: 'qtd' } // Bind series 1 to an axis named 'qtd'.
   },
   axes: {
    y: {
     valor: {label: 'total em R$', format: 'decimal'}, // Left y-axis.
     qtd: {side: 'qtd de vendas', label: 'Qtd de Vendas'}  // Right y-axis.
    }
   }   
  };

  
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('grafico3'));
  chart.draw(data, col_options);

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

 <div id="grafico1" style="width: 700px; height: 300px;"></div>
 <div id="grafico2" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
 <div id="grafico3" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

**can you help me?**

Comment: see `format` option in ColumnChart -- use that in BarChart -- `format: 'decimal'`

Comment: I tried but did not work
https://jsfiddle.net/almiroleal/5w3n1cku/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `NumberFormat` class to format the `data`,
before drawing the chart...

```
var formatNumer = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: 'decimal'});
formatNumer.format(data, 1);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar','corechart'], language:'pt_BR'});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Vendedores',  'Valor',  'n de vendas'],
      ['Vendedor 1',  24685.27, 298],
      ['Vendedor 2',  34415.24, 58],
      ['Vendedor 3',  76171.08, 615],
      ['Vendedor 4',  60106,    649],
      ['Vendedor 5',  38779.04, 445]
    ]);

    var formatNumer = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: 'decimal'});
    formatNumer.format(data, 1);

    var bar_options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Vendas em Valores',
        subtitle: 'por Vendedores'
      },
      series: {
        0: { axis: 'valor'}, // Bind series 0 to an axis named 'valor'.
        1: { axis: 'qtd' } // Bind series 1 to an axis named 'qtd'.
      },
      axes: {
        y: {
          valor: {label: 'total em R$', format: 'decimal'}, // Left y-axis.
          qtd: {side: 'qtd de vendas', label: 'Qtd de Vendas'}  // Right y-axis.
        },
      }     
    };
  
    
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('grafico1'));
    chart.draw(data, bar_options);

    var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Vendedores',  'Valor'],
      ['Vendedor 1',  24685.27],
      ['Vendedor 2',  34415.24],
      ['Vendedor 3',  76171.08],
      ['Vendedor 4',  60106],
      ['Vendedor 5',  38779.04]
    ]);
    var pie_options = {
      title: 'Percentual de Vendas',
      subtitle: 'por Vendedores',
      is3D: true
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('grafico2'));
    chart.draw(data2, pie_options );
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="grafico1" style="width: 700px; height: 300px;"></div>
<div id="grafico2" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
```